# How to generate an ISO message in j8583

Tags: java, iso8583, j8583

I have text data,

```
PROCESSINGCODE: 000000
SYSTEMTRACEAUDITNUMBER: 000001
Cardacceptorterminalidentification:3239313130303031
Reservednational:001054455354204D45535347
Networkmanagementinformationcode:0301
```

I need to generate an ISO Message with bitmap fields using j8583 project.

I have tried parsing a isomesssage, but I do not know how to generate an ISO Message.

**Note: I know that this can be done with jpos, but I need to do it with j8583.**

I have created below program.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


MessageFactory<IsoMessage> mf = new MessageFactory<IsoMessage>();
    try {
        //mfact = ConfigParser.createFromClasspathConfig("C:\\Users\\DHEERAJ\\workspace\\j8583.xml");

        String path="C:\\Users\\DHEERAJ\\workspace\\j8583.xml";
        ConfigParser.configureFromUrl(mf, new File(path).toURI().toURL());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }  
        mf.setForceSecondaryBitmap(true);
        mf.setUseBinaryBitmap(true);
        mf.setAssignDate(true);  
        mf.setTraceNumberGenerator(new SimpleTraceGenerator((int)  (System.currentTimeMillis() % 100000)));  
        System.out.println("NEW MESSAGE");  
        IsoMessage m = mf.newMessage(0200); 

       m.setValue(3, "000000", IsoType.ALPHA, 6);  
       m.setValue(11, "000001", IsoType.ALPHA, 6);  
        m.setValue(41, "3239313130303031", IsoType.ALPHA, 16);  
        m.setValue(60, "001054455354204D45535347", IsoType.ALPHA, 24);  
           m.setValue(70, "0301", IsoType.ALPHA, 4);

           m.setForceSecondaryBitmap(true);

}
```

**I have got below output.**

V0080¢    €        00000010201245030000013239313130303031001054455354204D455353470301

This output doesn't have bitmap values, and have some unwanted values at start.

Can someone please help with this?

Thanks.

Comment: My I please know the reason behind downvote for question? I am welcome to any suggestion for improvements. Thanks

Comment: Well for a start, this looks like a "write some code for me" question.  Or a request for a tutorial or something.

Comment: @StephenC I have updated my question with code as well. :) Any other suggestion? Thanks

Comment: Can someone help with this?

Comment: You will have to wait for someone who understands `j8583` to help you.

Comment: There _is_ a bitmap, but you have set it to binary format that's why it looks funny. Other than that, that is exactly the way you create a new ISO message with j8583.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following Java code prints `0200A220000000800010040000000000000000000010240507450000013239313130303031001054455354204D455353470301`, in which you can see the bitmap information.

```
import com.solab.iso8583.MessageFactory;
import com.solab.iso8583.IsoMessage;
import com.solab.iso8583.IsoType;
import com.solab.iso8583.parse.ConfigParser;
import com.solab.iso8583.impl.SimpleTraceGenerator;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

class Sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Check http://j8583.sourceforge.net/javadoc/index.html

        MessageFactory<IsoMessage> mf = new MessageFactory<IsoMessage>();

        try {
            String path="j8583.xml";
            ConfigParser.configureFromUrl(mf, new File(path).toURI().toURL());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mf.setForceSecondaryBitmap(true);
        mf.setUseBinaryBitmap(true);
        mf.setAssignDate(true); // This sets field 7 automatically
        mf.setTraceNumberGenerator(new SimpleTraceGenerator((int)  (System.currentTimeMillis() % 100000)));

        IsoMessage m = mf.newMessage(0x200); // You must use 0x200, 0x400, etc.
        m.setValue(3, "000000", IsoType.ALPHA, 6);
        m.setValue(11, "000001", IsoType.ALPHA, 6);
        m.setValue(41, "3239313130303031", IsoType.ALPHA, 16);
        m.setValue(60, "001054455354204D45535347", IsoType.ALPHA, 24);
        m.setValue(70, "0301", IsoType.ALPHA, 4);
        m.setForceSecondaryBitmap(true);

        System.out.println(m.debugString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Considering "A220000000800010" as primary bitmap in ouput, decodeing first 2 chars A2 into binary "10100010" says that field 3 and 7 is present. But in your code, there is no field 7. Am I missing something! Also where are you setting MTI as 0080 in code?

Comment: Hi, sorry for that, I copied your code as is. Now I edited my answer changing the line where you generate the new message to `IsoMessage m = mf.newMessage(0x200);`. Note the MTI parameter is now `0x200` instead of `0200`, as stated in the [j8583 Java docs](http://j8583.sourceforge.net/javadoc/index.html). That generates the following message: `0200A220000000800010040000000000000000000010240507450000013239313130303031001054455354204D455353470301`. Regarding field 7, you set it by using this line `mf.setAssignDate(true);`. I strongly recommend checking out the Java docs, they are well written :)